# git rebase shows conflicts that are already resolved in subsequent commit

Tags: git

I keep hitting the case where I have a PR, need to merge in changes from master and fix conflicts in a new commit (rather than rebase, because others may be working the same branch), then once the PR is approved I need to squash and rebase the commit.

Here is my commit layout that I want to squash/rebase

```
commit1: Merge branch master into this branch. Manually resolved conflicts in foo/file0 
commit0: Added feature.
```

When rebasing on master it gets to commit0 and detects that there are conflicts, even though those conflicts are resolved in commit1. Note that

```
#git rebase -i master

pick commit0 Initial commit

Could not apply commit0... Initial commit
Auto-merging foo/file0
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo/file0
```

I have tried accepting my changes each time rather than the incoming ones from master; though after doing that I am left with conflicts that had already been resolved in commit1.

What is the best way to squash and rebase the commits without needing to repeat the manual conflict resolutions that I did in commit1?

Comment: ... sure but rebase applies revisions one at a time so it might produce conflicts that are taken care of by other later revisions. So it happens. No way to go around it.... at least, not with rebase. Perhaps should consider using `git rerere`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `git rerere`, perhaps, as [eftshift0 suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574577/git-rebase-shows-conflicts-that-are-already-resolved-in-subsequent-commit#comment119441577_67574577), but I think it's simpler to squash first, then rebase.

Depending on how fancy / clever / reliable you want this to be, it could get a bit tricky.  I was curious about this and wrote this up.  It's *very* lightly tested.  It may not be as useful as you might think, though.  Save it as a file named `git-squashbase`, somewhere in your `$PATH`, and run `git squashbase master` for instance, after merging master into the current feature and resolving conflicts.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

OPTIONS_KEEPDASHDASH=
OPTIONS_STUCKLONG=
OPTIONS_SPEC="git squashbase [options] upstream

Using the given upstream, first squash this branch, then rebase it.
--
i,interactive  run git rebase --interactive instead of just making one commit
onto=          passed to final rebase
"

# parse options (defined above) and obtain "die" function etc.
. git-sh-setup

# Turn anything acceptable to git rev-parse into a commit hash ID.
# If it's not a commit hash ID, or unacceptable, quit now.
get_commit()
{
    local hash=$(git rev-parse --verify "$1") || exit
    hash=$(git rev-parse "${hash}^{commit}") || exit
    echo $hash
}

interactive=false
onto=false; target=
while :; do
    case "$1" in
    --) shift; break;;
    -i) interactive=true; shift;;
    --onto) onto=true; target=$(get_commit "$2"); shift 2;;
    esac
done

case $# in 1) ;; *) usage; esac

# Require a clean working tree and index.
require_clean_work_tree squashbase

# Everybody remember where we parked...
orig=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit
have_sym_orig=true
sym_orig=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD 2>/dev/null) || have_sym_orig=false

# ... and where we're going.
upstream_orig="$1"
upstream=$(get_commit "$1")
$onto || target=$upstream

# Return to where we started.
go_home()
{
    if $have_sym_orig; then
        git checkout -q $sym_orig || exit
    else
        git checkout -q $orig || exit
    fi
}

# Bind original branch name to the current (HEAD) hash ID.
# Assumes index and working tree are in order.
set_home_here()
{
    if $have_sym_orig; then
        git checkout -q -B $sym_orig HEAD || exit
    fi
}

# Set ORIG_HEAD to whatever HEAD had at the start of the whole
# thing.
set_orig_head()
{
    git update-ref -m "squashbase" ORIG_HEAD $orig
}

# We have some series of commits:
#
#            A--B--C   <-- topic (HEAD)
#           /
#  ...--o--*--o--o--o   <-- upstream
#
# We must locate commit `*`, i.e., the commit that is the
# parent of commit A.  Commit A must be an ordinary commit,
# not a merge commit.  Also, we must forbid a case like this:
#
#              A-_
#             /   \
#            /  B--C
#           /  /
#  ...--o--*--*--o--o   <-- upstream
#
# But we must *allow* this case:
#
#           A--B--C---M   <-- topic (HEAD)
#          /         /
#  ...--o--*--o--o--*   <-- upstream
#
# where the current commit is a merge with the upstream, and one
# of its parents *is* the upstream.
#
# I've attempted to do this with --boundary though I am not sure
# this catches every case.  It does work for simple cases, though.

set -- $(git rev-list --boundary $upstream..HEAD |
    sed -n -e "/^-$upstream$/d" -e 's/^-//p')
case $# in
0) die "no boundary commits with $upstream_orig";;
1) ;;
*) die "multiple boundary commits with $upstream_orig";;
esac

# Detach HEAD now before we start fussing, so that branch name $sym_orig
# does not get extra reflog updates.  And, if something goes wrong after
# this point, use quit_early to attempt to put everything back.
quit_early()
{
    go_home
    exit 1
}
git checkout -q --detach || exit

# XXX this signal trapping is ugly and not well tested
trap : 1 2 3 15
if $interactive; then
    git rebase -i $1 || quit_early
    # At this point we have whatever commits the user left
    # us.  We will assume that these are the "right" commits
    # to rebase now.
else
    git checkout -q --detach $1 || quit_early
    # This merge *must* work, but --squash implies -n ...
    git merge --squash $orig || quit_early
    # ... so commit it now, with --edit
    git commit --edit || quit_early
    # At this point we have a single commit (from git merge --squash).
    # This is the "right" commit to rebase now.
fi

# We always use a non-interactive rebase here.  Note that this
# step may fail, or stop in the middle, so we must first re-attach
# HEAD as appropriate.  This is a bit unfortunate as we'll get one
# extra reflog entry, but there's no way around that.
set_home_here
git rebase --onto $target $upstream || {
    status=$?
    echo "You will have to finish the rebase yourself now."
    set_orig_head
    exit $status
}

# The rebase worked.  We already re-attached HEAD so the only thing
# we really want to do now is override the ORIG_HEAD that rebase set:
# we want the one from before the squashbase operation.
set_orig_head
exit 0
```